# Does any of the atoms actually "survive" in plasma?

Tags: plasma-physics, atoms

Or does this state of matter detach electrons from all the atoms?

Thank you.

Comment: https://scied.ucar.edu/learning-zone/sun-space-weather/plasma

Comment: Try an online search for `ionization fraction`. [Partially ionized plasmas](https://lweb.cfa.harvard.edu/~namurphy/Lectures/Ay253_2016_13_Partially_Ionized_Plasmas.pdf).

Answer (score -1):

Plasma by definition is a gas which is made of charged particles. To form charged particles, all of the atoms have to be destroyed so that there can be a charge imbalance with the exception being partially ionized plasma.

However, even in this case, it is really just plasma mixed with a regular gas(though probably superheated) and so the plasma component of the "partially ionized plasma" would have all its atoms lose electrons, though it is not necessary that an atom loses all its electrons and each atom losing one electron is sufficient. The part that is not ionized is really just a gas mixed in with the plasma which has the possibility of easily becoming plasma with just a bit more heat but not true plasma just yet.

So basically, plasma requires that gasses have their atoms stripped of electrons but plasma can have gasses mixed into them and not all atoms in that plasma-gas mixture has to have its electrons taken away.